# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined

Tags: angular7

I want to use recorder service in my angular application in production environment  .
I use angular 7.
I want to access the server using my IP address instead of localhost.

I try with this code which work perfectly with dev environment and using localhost and it works using chrome browser.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import MicRecorder from 'mic-recorder-to-mp3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recorder',
  templateUrl: './recorder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recorder.component.scss']
})
export class RecorderComponent {

  recorder = new MicRecorder({
    bitRate: 128,
    audio: true,

  });

  constructor() {

  }

  start() {
      this.recorder.start().then(() => {

      }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });

  }
```

I have this error using the same code in production environment and using IP address instead of localhost

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined
```